# Prog Language lab

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I had a problem with the last part of my Prolog language lab.

This is what I have so far :

```
student(bob).     
student(lily).
student(ella).
teacher(david). 
taking(lily, csc324). 
taking(ella, csc324).

happy(X) :- 
  taking(X, csc324).
```

Now I need to create this :

`onlyHello(L)` holds if `L` is a list of size one containing the atom `hello`. 
(You can use a fact.)

I tried this but I guess I am wrong

```
L([]).

onlyHello(L) :- 
   L([hello]).
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a service for doing your homework for you.

Comment: I am sorry , I tried this L([X]).
onlyHello(L) :- L([hello]). but i guess I am wrong

Comment: `L(...` would be a syntax error, because variables in Prolog are capitalized and nothing else can be. The answer below is correct.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for being helpful and sorry again for inconvenience but I tried l([X]).
onlyHello(l) :- l([hello]). and it's always giving me true.

Comment: What I'm not understanding is why you want to seemingly _call_ the variable with arguments. Why do you think the body should have `l([hello])` or `L([hello])`? It seems like either the answer by @User9213 below, or something more oblique like `onlyHello(L) :- L = [hello].` but I don't quite know what got you stuck on trying to call the variable.

Comment: Because OnlyHello should not give me the value of L it should give me TRUE if L have hello in the list . or I guess I am understanding the question wrong

Comment: In Prolog there is no difference between "onlyHello(L) should return true if L is a list with one item and containing hello" and `onlyHello([hello]).`.

Comment: oh I got it now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Just write:

```
onlyHello([hello]).
```

If you plan on using Stackoverflow to get help with your homework, you need to learn to ask better questions.

Comment: I appreciate your help , it's my first time using stackoverflow so I didn't know how to ask , because I tried everything but I couldn't find the right answer .

Comment: It would be more polite to refer the OP to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DanielLyons How polite of you to do it for me. Thank you so much.